# Is it possible to further optimize this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I was running a query of this kind of query:

```
SELECT
-- fields
FROM
table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.c1 = table.c1 OR table1.c2 = table2.c2)
WHERE
-- conditions
```

But the `OR` made it very slow so i split it into 2 queries:

```
SELECT
-- fields
FROM
table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.c1 = table.c1
WHERE
-- conditions

UNION 

SELECT
-- fields
FROM
table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.c2 = table.c2
WHERE
-- conditions
```

Which works much better but now i am going though the tables twice so i was wondering if there was any further optimizations for instance getting set of entries that satisfies the condition (table1.c1 = table.c1 OR table1.c2 = table2.c2) and then query on it. That would bring me back to the first thing i was doing but maybe there is another solution i don't have in mind. So is there anything more to do with it or is it already optimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting the query into two separate ones is usually better in MySQL since it rarely uses "Index OR" operation (*Index Merge* in MySQL lingo).

There are few items I would concentrate for further optimization, all related to indexing:

**1. Filter the rows faster**

The predicate in the `WHERE` clause should be optimized to retrieve the fewer number of rows. And, they should be analized in terms of selectivity to create indexes that can produce the data with the fewest filtering as possible (less reads).

**2. Join access**

Retrieving related rows should be optimized as well. According to selectivity you need to decide which table is more selective and use it as a driving table, and consider the other one as the nested loop table. Now, for the latter, you should create an index that will retrieve rows in an optimal way.

**3. Covering Indexes**

Last but not least, if your query is still slow, there's one more thing you can do: use covering indexes. That is, expand your indexes to include all the rows from the driving and/or secondary tables in them. This way the InnoDB engine won't need to read two indexes per table, but a single one.

Answer (score 1):

Test

```
SELECT
-- fields
FROM
table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.c1 = table2.c1
WHERE
-- conditions

UNION ALL

SELECT
-- fields
FROM
table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.c2 = table2.c2
WHERE
-- conditions
/* add one more condition which eliminates the rows selected by 1st subquery */
  AND table1.c1 != table2.c1
```

---

Copied from the comments:

> Nico Haase > What do you mean by "test"?

OP shows query patterns only. So I cannot predict does the technique is effective or not, and I suggest OP to test my variant on his structure and data array.

> Nico Haase > what you've changed

I have added one more condition to 2nd subquery - see added comment in the code.

> Nico Haase > and why?

This replaces UNION DISTINCT with UNION ALL and eliminates combined rowset sorting for duplicates remove.

Comment: Oops! My bad . .

Comment: @NicoHaase *What do you mean by "test"?* OP shows query patterns only. So I cannot predict does the technique is effective or not, and I suggest OP to test my variant on his structure and data array. *what you've changed* I have added one more condition to 2nd subquery - see added comment in the code. *and why?* This replaces UNION DISTINCT with UNION ALL and eliminates combined rowset sorting for duplicates remove.

Comment: It's ok, i was just asking for general optimization guidelines, nothing directly related to my current problem. You don't need to argue over specific things :). Though i did not think about adding some conditions to exclude each selection from the other, thanks for that.

Comment: @Mechanizen *i was just asking for general optimization guidelines* Premature optimization may give errorneous results.

Comment: That is why i am asking this question, i tried to optimize this further in some ways but i was not getting the same results. I am still learning so i wanted to have a glimpse of what is possible without necessarily applying it, it already works fine as it is.

Comment: The Optimization is not finished until the optimal index(es) are added.  We need to know what is in "conditions" before we can help with that.

Comment: @Mechanizen You understand me uncorrectly. The same optimization may be successful, neutral or harmful depends on tables statistic, optimizator settings, server characteristics  and another factors... the same optimization on the same data array but on different servers may be effective on one server and may has no effect on another one... and even  demonstrate opposite effect.

Comment: The thing is the database i'm working on is quite old (15+ years) and contains a measurable amount of data but it is made in such a way that it's hard to get basic things from it without doing joins and unions. In my position i don't have the power, the time or the competences to change, and even if i could there are other implications that would make it difficult. So i am simply searching to make the most optimised queries in spite of the wonky structure...

Comment: But yeah, i understand that if i want to totaly optimise something i would have to tinker with indexes and structure and it depends of a lot of things (server, config, etc...) but i cannot dive into that, thus why my initial question was rather general.

Comment: @NicoHaase Done.